# I am trying to add a class to a certain div and it is only adding it to one of the div's with this ID, why?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to add a class to a div based on when this wheel stops on a tile. I am newer to javascript and I am trying to learn. It works when the wheel stops on the first label in the data variable but not the others, why? Here is the javascript that adds the class to the div

```js
var name = document.getElementById("slide-area");
 var divname = document.getElementById("question-slide");
 var number = divname.getAttribute("data-number");
 var pickvalue = data[picked].value;
 if(pickvalue == number){ 
 divname.className += " display";    
  }
```

Here is a link to my code https://code.sololearn.com/WM3ISd3OEEUc

Comment: IDs are unique identifiers. There should only be one element on the page with a given ID. You can use a class to identify groups of similar objects like this, you can use `document.getElementsByClassName`.

Comment: So I tried changing the divname to target by class and it ceases to work and it stops the wheel from spinning again. Any inclination as to why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking closer at what you're trying to do, the root problem is indeed that `id` needs to be unique in a page, there cannot be more than one element with the same one. But instead of using classes to classify a certain type of object, one simple method is to just make the ids unique by suffixing them with a number, like so (note the numbers on the end of the `id`s:

```
<div id="question-slide1" class="question-display" data-number="1">
    <h1>hello world 1</h1>
</div>
<div id="question-slide2" class="question-display" data-number="2">
    <h1>hello world 2</h1>
</div>
<div id="question-slide3" class="question-display" data-number="3">
    <h1>hello world 3</h1>
</div>
```

Then in your javascript code, you can build the `id` using the number that was picked:

```
container.on("click", spin);

var pickvalue = data[picked].value;
var name = document.getElementById("slide-area");
var divname = document.getElementById("question-slide" + pickvalue);
var number = divname.getAttribute("data-number");

if(pickvalue == number){ 
    divname.className += " display";
}
```

Here it is in action: https://code.sololearn.com/Wst1Zv2nAzwf/#html

Comment: Perfect! Thanks!

Comment: Bonus points if you can tell me how to removed the display class from any div that had the class previously applied. I've tried several different methods and none of them seem to be working.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that `id` attribute must be unique. There will always be only one `div` on that page that JS can pick up under the selector `#question-slide`. Better pick these by a class:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.slide-area .question-display').forEach(div => {
  // do stuff to the div
});
```

The fact is that the browser renders your invalid HTML. The browser engines always lean in that direction, "fix" the broken HTML as best as they can, if they can. So they only ever take the first `#question-slide` div to give to JavaScript. The others were "fixed" under the hub, even though your DOM tree still shows this invalid structure.

Comment: So should my if statement go in between those brackets?